# passing jmeter sampler result from groovy

Tags: groovy, jmeter

I'm new to JMeter and am trying to write some Groovy Samplers. I am having trouble finding documentation/examples of how to communicate with the JMeter framework from the script code. I was hoping someone could point me to a good starting point for the documentation.

I tried the following in a  JSR223 sampler

```
import org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult;
println(" running test") 
SampleResult sr=new SampleResult();
sr.setResponseCode("300");
sr.setSuccessful(false);
sr.setErrorCount(2);
sr.setResponseData("This is the response");
ResponseCode=300
return sr;
```

But it looks as if it had no effect. Looking in a results tree listener output the  sampler result is

```
Thread Name: Thread Group 1-1
Sample Start: 2016-03-22 17:38:07 CDT
Load time: 12
Connect Time: 0
Latency: 0
Size in bytes: 0
Headers size in bytes: 0
Body size in bytes: 0
Sample Count: 1
Error Count: 0
Response code: 200
Response message: OK
```

....

Answer (score 6):

It won't work that way.

If you look into JSR223 Sampler GUI you will see some pre-defined variables like:

- ctx
- vars
- props
- SampleResult
- etc.

[image: JSR223 Pre Defined Variables]

So you already have an instantiated [SampleResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html) which can be used directly like:

```
SampleResult.setResponseCode("300");
SampleResult.setSuccessful(false);
SampleResult.setErrorCount(2);
SampleResult.setResponseData("This is the response");
```

For more information on using groovy scripts and scripting best practices check out [Beanshell vs JSR223 vs Java JMeter Scripting: The Performance-Off You've Been Waiting For!](https://blazemeter.com/blog/beanshell-vs-jsr223-vs-java-jmeter-scripting-its-performance) guide.

Comment: Thank you that is an excellant answer and just what I was looking for! BUt still having an issue. If I reference the SampleResult as "SampleResult" the script throws an error :

Comment: If I reference the SampleResult as "SampleResult" the script throws an error " No signature of method: static org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult.setSuccessful() ".  If I access it as "sampleResult"  groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: sampleResult for class: Script135. In the first case it is trying to access as if these were static methods on the class in the later the reference seems wrong. Do I need to explicitly import the property somehow?

Comment: got it, I should not import SampleResult. Then the static method error does not occur

Answer (score 0):

JMeter 5.4 JSR223 Sampler

[more](https://jmetervn.com/2016/12/20/jsr223-with-groovy-variables-part-2/)

```
//set Response Code
SampleResult.setResponseCode("201");
SampleResult.setSuccessful(false);
 
//set Response Message
SampleResult.setResponseMessage("This is message returned from JSR223 script");
 
//set Response Data
SampleResult.setResponseData("You will see this sentence in Response Data tab", "UTF-8");

println( "The Sample Label is : " + SampleResult.getSampleLabel() );
println( "The Start Time in miliseconds is : " + SampleResult.getStartTime() );
println( "The Response Code is : " + SampleResult.getResponseCode() );
println( "The Response Message is : " + SampleResult.getResponseMessage() );
```